# Find Object in Object Array Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, search

I have a custom object array of type `LeaderboardUser()`. This object contains a string variable of "uid", "email".

I am trying to make a statement to recognize if the uid given matches the uid of the `LeaderBoard`

```
if self.allFriends.contains() {
    // Remove user
    Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("Friends").child(self.uid).removeValue()
} else {
    // Add user
    let key = Database.database().reference().child("Users").childByAutoId().key
    let friends = ["uid" : "\(self.uid)"] as [String : Any]
    let totalList = ["\(key!)" : friends]
    Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("Friends").updateChildValues(totalList)
}
```

Is there any way that I can search the UID parameter?
I tried a contains() bool, but I don't know what and how how that works.

Comment: I am assuming that `allFriends` is the array containing elements of type `LeaderboardUser`?

Comment: Searching for the title of this question and the tag [swift] generated 800 hits, surely some should be helpful, [find object in array](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+find+object+in+array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `contains(where:` method here.

```
if self.allFriends.contains(where: { $0.uid == uidOfLeaderBoard }) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Param of contents func is a closure that takes an element of the sequence as its argument and returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the passed element represents a match

```
@inlinable public func contains(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool
```

you can using it like:

```
        if allFriends.contains(where: { (leaderboardUser) -> Bool in
            return leaderboardUser.uid == idYouWantToFind
        }) {

        }
```

or with sort version:

```
        if allFriends.contains(where: { $0.uid == idYouWantToFind}) {

        }
```

and if you make your LeaderboardUser comfort to Equatable protocol, you can use like this:

```
class LeaderboardUser: Equatable {
    var uid: String = ""
    var email: String = ""

    static func == (lhs: LeaderboardUser, rhs: LeaderboardUser) -> Bool {
        return lhs.uid == rhs.uid
    }
}
```

```
        if allFriends.contains(userWantToFind) {

        }
```